# Can I match my particle density to my displacement map?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing, particles, workflow

[image: Node map]

I have a plane which uses a noise texture as a displacement map.

I want to put some grass on the plane as particles and match the particle density to the displacement map but I can't find a way to link/save the texture. What is the correct process for this?

Comment: Hello :) Is every instance of noise inherently the same and just scaled/detailed differently? I assumed it was randomized every time

Comment: It's not randomized. It always uses [the same formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise) to calculate the noise. So, every instance of the noise texture looks the same, if the scale is the same. (gotta admit, I learned all this in the past 15 minutes :).

Comment: That's great! Let me try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a *Mapping node*, to better control the *location/scale/rotation* of your texture.

*Noise texture* always uses [the same formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise) to calculate the noise. 
So every instance of the noise texture looks the same.

*Add a Mapping node, so you can precisely control the output.*
[image]

Comment: So the "Noise" option in the texture menu is different (it appears to similar to the White Noise texture node), there is an Original Perlin noise in the "Clouds" texture but that's got different parameters. Also it turns out hair cannot be displaced anyway (https://developer.blender.org/T50091) :( I think I'll just use displacements again to create grass and see if it works. Thanks for the help though!